# Monitoring multiple processes using zookeeper

Tags: distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper

I'm utilizing Zookeeper to track the state of multiple processes running in many servers. I have modelled each of the processes belonging to different categories in a tree like structure. Each process is the leaf znode marked as ephemeral.

The doubt i have is :

=> Can i maintain a single static instance of zookeeper connection and utilize this connection for multiple processes to register themselves as a Znode or is it ok, if a zookeeper session is created for every process.

I've read quite a bit on Zookeeper but still couldn't get a clear idea of the Zookeeper sessions. Please can you help me with this

Comment: How would you make a static connection and use it by multiple processes to create znodes?

Each process having its own zk connection/session is a standard pattern. That way, if a connection is lost or process goes down, the ephemeral node is deleted and your process is properly detected as gone.

Comment: When you say "processes", are you referring to different operating system processes? This is, each process has its very own PID? If so, you must have different connections for each process. This way, when a specific process dies, you get an specific event.

Comment: Thanks for the information igorbel and PEdroArthur. I didn't understand zookeeper clearly enough before. Now i understand it. I'll have separate connections for each process. Yes i was referring to operating system process with own pid.